# Is it possible to auto-decline meeting requests that are scheduled to occur on specific days?

Tags: google-calendar-api

How can I auto-decline meeting requests that are scheduled to take place on Mondays?

**Some context:**

Mondays are full-on days for me, and I literally have things to do for the entire day.

I get a lot of meeting requests; some of those requests take place on Mondays.

It would be great if I could set Google Calendar up to automatically decline events that are scheduled to occur on Mondays.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A relocation/migration would be useful in that case.

Comment: Stack only allows relocation and migration to a few sites unfortunately and webapps is not one of them.

Comment: Perhaps SuperUser would be suitable.